# Stack implemented via a linked-list in C

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

The following code is part of a stack implementation, implemented via a linked-list, in C. Are there problems with the code?  Specifically, in the `pop()` method the caller passes a `void**` argument so `pop()` can assign a pointer to the top node's data to it.  `pop()` subsequently calls `delete` to free the stack's top node, which is where `*data` is pointing.  Won't this delete the data in the pointer that should be returned to the caller, or am I missing something?

```
typedef struct Element 
{
    struct Element *next;
    void *data;
} Element;


bool pop( Element **stack, void **data )
{
    Element *elem;
    if (!(elem = *stack)) return false;

    *data = elem->data;
    *stack = elem->next;
    delete elem;
    return true;
}


bool push( Element **stack, void *data )
{
    Element *elem = new Element;
    if(!elem) return false;

    elem->data = data;
    elem->next = *stack;
    *stack = elem;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The typedef isn't doing anything useful - the code is explicitly using knowledge of the underlying type (struct), and that type *has* a type, so you're not getting any extra type checking.  The reader however has to remember in his head what the underlying type is, rather than just being able to read it in the code in front of him.

Comment: "delete" is not a C function - it is C++.

Comment: This is most definitely C++, not C. I suggest you update the question and tag.

Comment: This is terrible code.  It's unintuitive.  A stack is not a complicated data structure!

Comment: Some ideas to simplify. If you can use std::queue use that. Alternatively if the stack can have a maximum size, simply use a static array and a pointer. Alternatively if the objects are entirely in the domain of your application and they only ever appear in one container, add internal links to your objects (which has the added advantage objects can see their own neighbors and perform their own operations such as unlink themselves).

Comment: @Blank Xavier, in (at least some versions of) C, the `typedef` saves you from specifying `struct` in saying `bool pop( struct Element **stack, void **data )`. Not useless.

Comment: Probably best to post a "question" like this on codereview.SE.

Comment: @ikegami: not using struct has the effect of obscuring the underlying type.  This makes the code harder to read - that's not an advantage!

Comment: That's not true, @Blank Xavier. Noone's going to see `Element` and think it could be a primitive. It's such a common practice that I don't remember ever seeing code that didn't use it.

Comment: @ikegami: that's not the problem.  People reading it will know what it is - it's a typedef. What they *won't* know is the underlying type. Comprehending code when you do not know the type of a variable is *much* harder. You can *find out* the type, by looking it up - but then you have to remember it. Now repeat with say 20 or more typedefs for different types - and almost all of the time, the way the code is written *requires* the underlying type - like here, using "->" on a struct pointer.  So the type is hidden, but the use of the type is not. All it does is make life hard for the reader.

Comment: @Blank Xavier, I've already said they *do* know the underlying type. There's no way they're going to think it's a primitive. That only leaves structs. Using the `struct` keyword is redundant. Unlike your theory, this isn't hypothetical. It's extremely widely used without causing confusion.

Comment: They know the underlying type because they looked it up in the header file. Now imagine a million lines of code and a corrisponding increase in the number of typedefs, a certain number of which are structs, but others are of integer types - signed, unsigned, different lengths, enums. Now imagine the code base is badly written and you're unfamiliar with most of it. You come to some code - there's say a dozen typedefs in there and you don't know their types. The code does a lot of manipulation of those types - is that code valid or not? you can't know without memorizing all the underlying types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pop` implementation is okay as is.  The `Element` structure and data pointer are two separate chunks of memory.  Deleting the list element does not delete the data pointed to by its member.   You can see that maybe more clearly in the  `push` function.  It creates a new `Element` and sets its data pointer to the given memory.

Comment: I'd just return the data pointer in pop(), so its value can be used again by the caller - and be deallocated if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  For some reason I missed the fact that the struct had a pointer to the data and NOT the data itself, and therefore deleting the struct does not in fact, delete the data.

Answer (score 3):

A few thoughts:

- If you want to compile this with a C compiler, use malloc() and free() instead of new and delete. Those are C++ keywords.
- If you need a quick way to determine the size of the stack, I suggest making a Stack data structure that holds the head and tail pointers and the stack's length, then pass that into your push() and pop() functions. On top of that, you won't need double pointers.
- Return the data pointer from your pop() function and don't forget to free() it (if necessary).

Comment: +1 for container structures and return values instead of double pointers

Comment: Reguarding the third point, I'd like to add that `NULL` could be returned to indicate the stack is empty. This prevents `NULL` from being placed in the stack, but I doubt that this is an issue for this particular stack.